# Go Restful API : CORS configuration works with React but not with Angular

Tags: reactjs, angular, rest, go, cors

I hope you are doing well.
Please, I have this RESTFul API build using Go and Gorilla/mux and rs/cors.
Here is the router handler with cors set up

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

    r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    r.HandleFunc("/healthz", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("I'm alive")
    })
    r.HandleFunc("/api/analysis/{projectId}", List).Methods(http.MethodGet, http.MethodOptions)      // list all charts
    r.HandleFunc("/api/analysis/{projectId}", Create).Methods(http.MethodPost, http.MethodOptions)   // create a chart
    r.HandleFunc("/api/analysis/{projectId}", Delete).Methods(http.MethodDelete, http.MethodOptions) // delete a chart

    return r
}
```

Here is how I'm starting the server

```
    r := NewRouter()

    r.Use(loggingMiddleware)
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(r)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", handler))
```

**cors** is from https://github.com/rs/cors

From an Angular Web application, I'm calling the route http://localhost:5000/api/analysis/6023d34440baf5016e5b74ea but I receive a **Cors error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader**

From a React.js Web application, I don't receive any error, **No errors !!** Successful request

I have also tried the CORS configuration from MUX https://github.com/gorilla/mux#handling-cors-requests but it didn't also works.

Please, what am I doing wrong?
How can I fix that?

Comment: What port is the angular app running on and what is the react running on? (e.g. localhost:3000)

Comment: Reactjs localhost:9999 - Angular localhost:4200 - Go API localhost:5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your angular/react apps via the `start` command (or however angular is run) you may need to specify the full URL of where these apps are running (e.g. `localhost:9999`) for the CORS allowed origins header.

**Also two other points:**

1. Remove the `http.MethodOptions` from the `Methods` part on your routes - whenever an options HTTP method is detected, the CORS handler will handle it. I don't think those endpoints are ever triggered (because the CORS handler should intercept them), but it's misleading to have the `http.MethodOptions` in there.
2. Are you creating two routers? First with `r:= mux.NewRouter()` and then again with `r:= NewRouter()` - or is this just a mix up from copy/pasting it?

This can be done for `rs/cors` package as shown below:

```golang
r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
r.HandleFunc("/api/analysis/{projectId}", List).Methods(http.MethodGet)
// ... add other routes here

// Then wrap in the CORS handler
corsHandler := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost", "http://localhost:4200", "HTTP://localhost:9999"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"*"},
    }).Handler(r)

// Now serve the API
http.ListenAndServe(":5000", corsHandler)
```

And if you need cookies:

```golang
r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
r.HandleFunc("/api/analysis/{projectId}", List).Methods(http.MethodGet)
// ... add other routes here

// Then wrap in the CORS handler
corsHandler := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost", "http://localhost:4200", "HTTP://localhost:9999"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    }).Handler(r)

// Now serve the API
http.ListenAndServe(":5000", corsHandler)
```

Comment: Christian, concerning `r := NewRouter()`, I just updated the code

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am about to try it.

Comment: Christian, sorry but it's not working. I am still having the same CORS issue from the Angular web application

Comment: I added AllowedHeaders: []string{"*"} to make it works

Comment: This allows any resource to access the api, can you post a screenshot of the request headers on the angular app from within developer tools?

Comment: Here is the link of the screenshot in an ERROR situation https://ibb.co/kmygLq0

Comment: Here is the link of the screenshot in a successful request https://ibb.co/P4Y6Wzy